# iPhone X Safe Area Top Guide delayed calculation/ wrong alignment

Tags: ios, safearealayoutguide

I'm using a custom launch animation in my application. I have already updated my app to use the `Safe Area` instead of the traditional Layout Guides.

At the beginning of the transition animation, I get the frame of a UIView in the destination view controller aligned to the top safe area layout guide like so:

[image: Top Alignment Constraint]

And I animate a snapshot of an identical view from the center of the screen to that position.

A problem arises on the iPhone X (not any other devices) where the UIView actually animates to above it's final position, making the animation appear laggy.

The problem is that the frame I get from the view during the animation (before it's presented on the screen) is not the correct final frame of the view.

It seems as though the safe area top layout guide actually hasn't been set at that point, constraining my view to the top of the screen, which is the frame I read during the animation.

Does anyone know whether this is a bug, or if not, how I can get the actual correct frame of my uiview after the safe area top layout guide has been calculated before it's presented on the screen?

[Here is an example project showing the issue I'm having](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dcach5v1f99g5z/iPhoneX%20Safe%20Area%20Bug%20Demo.zip?dl=0). Please run on the iPhone X simulator.

[Here is a video showing the issue I'm experiencing on the iPhone X Simulator](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm6gjg4vn9fjp2e/Video.mov?dl=0).

Comment: Could you provide enough information so that we can reproduce the phenomenon for ourselves? Perhaps post an example project?

Comment: Sure, an example project has been added to the original question along with a video showing the issue I'm having. It's worth mentioning the comment in the `Animator` file, moving the code calculating the labels frame into the actual animation block seems to solve the problem. No idea why.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding an @IBOutlet for the top constraint of the view I'm animating and using the safeAreaInsets to calculate the correct height:

```
@IBOutlet var wifiImageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

...

view.safeAreaInsets.top + wifiImageViewTopConstraint.constant
```

So in my case the top constant to safe area is 50 so
- for an iPhone X it will be 44 + 50 = 94
- for other phones it will be 20 + 50 = 70